# How to enable ActiveMQ embedded kahadb using bean configuration

Tags: java, spring, persistence, activemq-classic

I need to enable local persistence of activemq embedded broker by enabling kahadb. How can i configure kahadb in bean xml file.

```
<bean id="producerBroker" class="org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">

        <property name="brokerName" value = "producerBroker"/>
        <property name="persistent" value="true"/>
        <property name="transportConnectorURIs">
            <list>
                <value>tcp://localhost:7005</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="jmsBridgeConnectors">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.activemq.network.jms.JmsQueueConnector">
                    <property name="outboundQueueConnectionFactory">
                        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
                            <property name="brokerURL" value="http://localhost:8090" />
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                    <property name="outboundQueueBridges">
                        <list>
                            <bean class="org.apache.activemq.network.jms.OutboundQueueBridge">
                                <constructor-arg value="qvsample"/>
                            </bean>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**EDIT**

ActiveMQ's default persistence db is kahoDb. this line  `<property name="persistent" value="true"/>`made this. I need to know how to change this db to another. Moreover i need a good reference to configure spring xml file for activemq?

Comment: KahaDB is the default store when persistent=true so you need to supply some more information on what you are trying to accomplish and what hasn't worked for you

Comment: @Tim Bish Just checked default db of activemq is kahaDB. My fault is made producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT) while sending message. how can set this default db to other db (obviously i need good reference to learn activemq to spring xml description)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a bean of `org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBPersistenceAdapter` and inject it into your broker through `persistenceAdapter` property.

E.g.

```
<bean id="persistenceAdapter" class="org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBPersistenceAdapter">
    <property name="directory" value="D:\test"/>
</bean>

<bean id="producerBroker" class="org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="persistenceAdapter" ref="persistenceAdapter"/>
</bean>
```

You can use any other persistence adapter (e.g. leveldb) as long as it implements `org.apache.activemq.store.PersistenceAdapter`